# Short referencing a static function from an instance method of the same class in typescript

Tags: typescript

Referencing the full qualified name of the static function works.

```
class Shape {
  spin {
    Shape.log("something");
  }

  static log(text: string) {
  }
}
```

Is there a short way to reference the static "log" function ? Without the full class name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is currently no shorthand to access the static function in the local object.

As in your example, [you must use the fully-qualified name](http://aliolicode.com/2016/05/07/typescript-static-members/).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that calls `Shape.log`:

```
class Shape {
    spin() {
        log("something");
    }

    static log(text: string) {}
}

function log(message: string) {
    Shape.log(message)
}
```